# how to kill hudson job from bash script when log file doesn't change?

Tags: bash, hudson, monitoring

how can I kill hudson job from bash script when the log file doesn't change? (hudson is freezed).

Context: I have a bash script that check if a log file had change after X seconds and I want to modified it to check that if the timeout raises, and there's no error in console, this means that hudson job is freezed, so I want to be notified about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was to use the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash
#if the log file does not change
if [ "something" ]; then
    kill -9 $(pidof eclipse)
fi
```

This kills the eclipse instance (who's calls hudson), and continues with the build of the others elements and that it's Ok for my task.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the [Build Timeout plugin.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin)

Comment: It's not useful because there are long builds (12 days for example). The easiest approach is to check the timestamp of the log file.